# How to strech an image in a div of width:100%?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display the image on full screen width on my index page and height should be visible as one page height; like [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/). I have done it through css and also through scaled it thorough jQuery but none of it is working. What is the best way to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#animation img').each(function() {
    var maxWidth = $('animation').width; // div width;
    var width = $(this).width(); // current image width
    var ratio = $('#animation').width / width; // get ratio for scaling image
    if (maxWidth > width) {
      $(this).css("width", ratio * width); // scale  width based on ratio
    }
```

```css
#animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 706px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
#animation>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  // height:706px; 

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animation">
  <img src="image_5.jpg">// 850px * 450px
</div>
```

Comment: You've given us a link to apple.com and not your own? Any jsfiddle or codepen to help us :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you want image to be 100% width set just width: 100%;
In your example you set max-width: 100%; it means that image can't be wider than 100%

There is also another way, you can set width to 100vw which stands for 100 viewport width

Answer (score 0):

As in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/17o3aq7j/2/

```
#animation>img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#animation {
   width:100%;
}
#animation img{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And its working now...

```
 #animation {
        width:100%;
        height:700px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
        box-shadow:5px 5px 5px black;

        }

    #animation> img {
        width:100%;
        max-height:700px;   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code.  I recommend learning to use your browser's debugging tools (probably launched by hitting F12).

The functions weren't closed properly, so the whole thing wouldn't compile.

You were reading the .width property from $("#animation").  Without the "()" at the end, you were getting a reference to the function, which doesn't do anything interesting in when divided by a number.

The version below actually does something.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#animation img').each(function () {
        var maxWidth = $('#animation').width(); // div width;
        console.log(maxWidth);
        var width = $(this).width(); // current image width
        console.log(width);
        var ratio = $('#animation').width() / width; // get ratio for scaling image
        console.log(ratio);
        if (maxWidth >= width) {
            $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // scale  width based on ratio
        }
    });
});
```